# Using Data Annotation Validators with the Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, poco, data-annotations

I am working on WPF application which uses Entity Framework alongwith POCO classes. I would like to use data annotations with POCO classes for Client side validations in UI (WPF). Since, I can't modify the POCO classes (it will be regenerated after updating the entity model), therefore, I have implemented the data annotations using partial class as per approach mentioned in the article: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs under section "Using Data Annotation Validators with the Entity Framework". Somehow this approach is not working in my case. Can anybody suggest something as to how can I use data annotation with Entity Framework?

Comment: And what is the question? You have already found solution.

Comment: I am not able to make it working using Partial classes. Can you suggest something ?

Comment: If I specify the data annotations in POCO classes, it started working fine but not as per the approach mentioned in the above article. Any ideas ?

Comment: That approach is the solution. If it doesn't work for you, post the related code so that we can try to figure out the problem.

Comment: How are you using dataannotation in wpf. Post some code.

Comment: I used the same approach as per the above article but somehow its not working. If I specified the data annotations in the classes generated by EF, it works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to registered the Data Annotations. Just followed the steps mentioned in the article & its working now.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at the **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It shows how to use data annotations with the Entity Framework. And it shows how to consume it in WPF so that the validation errors are shown.